# Implement a each do loop in this

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, highcharts

How would I implement an each do loop here and leave out the comma for the last record? Code is based on [here](https://github.com/michelson/lazy_high_charts/wiki/Combination-Chart).

```
@h = LazyHighCharts::HighChart.new('graph') do |f|
   f.series(:type=> 'pie',:name=> 'Total consumption', :data=> [
        #implement a each do loop here  
        @products.each do |p|
        {
           :name=> p.name, :y=> p.price
        },
        end
        ])
end
```

I want the output to be:

```
{:name=> "Cereal", :y=> 5}, 
{:name=> "Dog Buscuits", :y=> 12},
{:name=> "Steak", :y=> 8} #i dont want a comma for the last record
```

but my current loop puts a comma in the end so i get a syntax error

```
{:name=> "Cereal", :y=> 5}, 
{:name=> "Dog Buscuits", :y=> 12},
{:name=> "Steak", :y=> 8}, #ERROR here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need an array as output, use map like

```
:data=> @products.map{ |p|{:name=> p.name, :y=> p.price} }
```